# Sum values from dataframe considering two column interval

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-manipulation

## Want to sum values from two column considering the intervals and overlaps.

### Sample example:

`df = data.frame(A = c(1, 1, 2), B = c(1, 600, 600), C = c(0.02, 0.03, 0.01))`

### Rules for summarization:

> For each column (A & B) the union are corresponding an index value for an individual interval. That I need to sum to create vector that I will use to perform financial projection / valuation. In the end, I would like to retrieve the overlaps inclued

#### for example:

1 to 600 - 0.03
2 to 600 - 0.01

#### From the value 2 to 600 i'm also including the interval 1 to 600, so I need to sum considering this overlap.

### Expected output of the sum:

```
### 1 - 0.05
### 2 - 0.04
### 600 - 0.04
```

### I think now I could explain everything:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your expected output and the underlying logic. How is there a row `2 - 0.04`? I've posted the attempt of an answer below with what I *think* you're asking.

Comment: Hmmm. I feel we are both not understanding each other. In the screenshot of your hand-written notes, what is the difference between points 2 and 3? Aren't they both discussing the "2-600" and "1-600" overlap? Why are they duplicated? The notes also don't explain the `2 - 0.04` expected output. What does the number 2 denote? Any why does the 0.05 overlap of `1-1` (whatever that is) and `1-600` get logged under a value of  `1`. What does the 1 denote here?

Comment: Consider each line as a fixed income bond. Columns A (initial term) and B (final term) in months for each one. At the end of the day, I need to unify considering all the time intervals summarized by the sum. As I explained earlier, the interval 2 - 600 it intersects with 1- 600, so I need to add to the interval 2 - 600 the rate applied in the interval 1 - 600, this applies in any case. I need to estimate these consolidated rates to generate a large vector of discount rates to be applied in each month of my portfolio

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications Matheus, but you are not really answering my question(s). (1) In `2 - 0.04` (your expected output) what does the `2` denote? (2) Why are there two duplicate "calculations" in your hand-written notes? (3) Why does the overlap of `1-1` and `1-600` get stored under a value of `1`?

Comment: This is because it has always managed to store time intervals and associated interest rates, consolidating all the assets in the portfolio. So, for the 1 month, I have to include the sum of both interest rates that start in the first period. For the 2 month I need to consider the rate for the period 2 - 600 and within the range 1 - 600, algo include intersection in period 2 - 600, so for 2 months until the end, I must consolidate summarize by the sum of these rates. Thus generating 2 - 0.04

Comment: Hi Matheus. I struggle to make sense of what you explain in the previous comment and how this answers my 3 separate questions (perhaps this is a language issue). I'll have to leave it at that since we don't seem to be able to move forward. Perhaps somebody else will be able to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You're leaving us guessing somewhat as to what the rules are for reproducing your expected output.

I can't reproduce your output but is this what you're after?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
    pivot_longer(-C, values_to = "id") %>% 
    select(-name) %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    summarise(value = sum(C))
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#     id value
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1  0.07
#2     2  0.01
#3   600  0.04
```

Comment: @MatheusMonteiro As I write in the comment above, I don't understand the logic behind your "summarisation". How do you get a value of 0.04 for a value of 2. What do the first and second value denote? Can you walk me through the calculation for every value? Please edit your original post (comments are transient) and include those details in the main post.

Comment: Thank you Maurits! It's close, but the problem is getting the sum optimally optimized. 

The rules for applying the sum is:

For each column (A & B) the union are corresponding an index value for an individual interval. That I need to sum to create vector that I will use to perform financial projection / valuation.

So, In the end, I would like to retrieve the overlaps inclued 

for example:

1 to 600 - 0.03
2 to  600 - 0.01
 
From the value 2 to 600 i'm also including the interval 1 to 600, so I need to sum considering this overlap. 

I ve script that perform matrix allocation

Comment: But it is taking too long, even I was thinking of passing it on to rcpp, but I imagine that there is some way to make this summary more efficient

Comment: Hi @MatheusMonteiro. I've checked your edit but this is still not clear to me. In your edit you're mainly repeating in prose what you've already given as sample data in code. It doesn't answer *how* you calculate those "sums". Why is the value for 2 -> 0.04? Why is the value for 1 -> 0.05? I have no idea what you mean by "optimally optimised"; I cannot see any optimisation problem.

Comment: [continued] From your post: *"For each column (A & B) the union are corresponding an index value for an individual interval. That I need to sum to create vector that I will use to perform financial projection / valuation. In the end, I would like to retrieve the overlaps inclued"* I'm sorry but I have no idea what you are saying here. Again, it would really help if you could *explicitly* walk us through a calculation.